# css drop down nav bar for mobile works but is invisible on iphones

Tags: html, css

I coded this website entirely in HTML and CSS without using any libraries. The dropdown menu works perfectly fine on any computer or Android phone and I have tested in using multiple web browsers. On iPhones, the dropdown menu doesn't appear on the screen.

I thought it had to do with the issue of iPhone not supporting `:hover`, but after a lot of testing and attempts to fix it, I have found that the hover is not the problem.  After clicking the nav, I have found that although not visible, the links in the dropdown menu work if I click on the correct place where it should be.  Essentially, the dropdown menu and the links are there, but they can't be seen.  I have tried adding `visiblity: visible`, `z-index: 999` and several different `display` values but the problem persists.

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  border: .05em solid #004EA8;
  width: 100%;
}

nav .logo {
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul,
nav:active ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  top: 3.8em;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-sections {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #004EA8;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li,
.dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropbtn a {
  color: #004EA8;
}

nav:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.dropbtn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-style: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.nav-button {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin: .75em .6em .4em 1em;
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.25em;
  height: 1.2em;
  margin-top: .85em;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  border-top: 0.2em solid #004EA8;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #004EA8;
}

.hamburger:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3em;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 0.2em solid #004EA8;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <nav class="navbar-items items-left">
    <img class="logo" src="images/NELS Logo 2145C.png" alt="New England Language School Building">
    <div class="nav-button navbar-link navbar-link-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-sections">
      <li class="single-line-link"><a href="index.html" class="current navbar-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="single-line-link"><a href="about.html" class="navbar-link">About</a></li>
      <li class="single-line-link">
        <div class="dropdown navbar-link">
          <button class="dropbtn"><a href="languages.html">Languages</a></button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="ESL.html">English</a>
            <a href="French.html">French</a>
            <a href="German.html">German</a>
            <a href="Italian.html">Italian</a>
            <a href="Japanese.html">Japanese</a>
            <a href="Mandarin.html">Mandarin</a>
            <a href="Portuguese.html">Portuguese</a>
            <a href="Spanish.html">Spanish</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Request a Language</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="single-line-link"><a href="corporate.html" class="navbar-link">Corporate</a></li>
      <li class="double-line-link"><a href="sessions.html" class="navbar-link">Session<br>Dates</a></li>
      <li class="single-line-link"><a href="events.html" class="navbar-link">Events</a></li>
      <li class="double-line-link"><a href="LanguagePartner.html" class="navbar-link">Language<br>Partner</a></li>
      <li class="single-line-link"><a href="photos.html" class="navbar-link">Photos</a></li>
      <li class="single-line-link"><a href="location.html" class="navbar-link">Location</a></li>
      <li class="single-line-link"><a href="policies.html" class="navbar-link">Policies</a></li>
      <li class="single-line-link"><a href="contact.html" class="navbar-link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Again, this is only an issue on iPhones. Any help would be hugely appreciated as I have spent hours/days searching for and trying different solutions that don't work.

I am including the code for the nav in HTML and the CSS to make the drop down menu work. To see the full code, you can visit the website at https://www.newenglandlanguage.com/

Comment: its showing in my system in iphone  when i click on navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this on Safari and the behaviour of the menu shows the same issue as you have described. To fix it just remove the `overflow: hidden` property from the `nav` element selector in your media queries.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That resolved the issue immediately!